# editrc: changing keybindings in /etc/editrc

Tags: command-line, asterisk

`Asterisk` uses the `editline` library, and the keybindings can be configured in `/etc/editrc`.

I have defined some of my own keybindins, some other are left to default values.

How can I print the current keybindings in Asterisk? I am looking for something similar to what `bindkey` does in `zsh`.

Also, how can I "unbind" a key, such as <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> ?

And How would I create new keybinding that would bind  <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to exit/quit ?

here is my current `/etc/editrc`:

```
bind "^W" ed-delete-prev-word
bind "\e[1;5D" vi-prev-word
bind "\e[1;5C" vi-next-word
bind ^[[5~ ed-search-next-history
bind ^[[6~ ed-search-prev-history
```

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation for /etc/editrc file even in the [Official repo](https://github.com/troglobit/editline) . But [here](https://github.com/troglobit/editline/blob/master/examples/cli.c#L155) is an example of how you can use the API to bind a key. And [here](https://github.com/troglobit/editline/blob/master/src/editline.c#L1942) is the keymap type which contains all of the possible keybindings for libeditline.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the editrc file or any official documentation for it ? I couldn't find anything regarding that in the asterisk docs.

Comment: I don't get anything with grepping through both asterisk and editline source code and searching for editrc file. I think in the current situation the best way to answer your question is to send an email directly to some of the [developers](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/graphs/contributors) of the project and asking for help.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi - I have edited my question, and added contents of `editrc`.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi - also, I assume that a solution to bind Ctrl+D might be generic to editrc, not specific to asterisk. That is why asterisk documentation does not mention it.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find anything useful in the editline docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like it uses NetBSD's editline, a.k.a. [libedit](https://thrysoee.dk/editline/).

See the [editrc man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=editrc&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html)

It looks like you can remove bindings using

```
bind -r ...
```

Or

```
bind ... ed-insert
```

And I guess the easiest thing is to try adding

```
bind
```

(without arguments) to the bottom of editrc to list all bindings.

To make Ctrl+D exit, I would try

```
bind ^d ed-end-of-file
```

If that doesn't work, you could try making it type "exit" for you using something like

```
bind -s ^d exit\n
```

Or you could make Ctrl+D act like Ctrl+C with

```
bind ^d ed-tty-sigint
```

Comment: so how do I bind ctrl+d to quit/exit ?

Comment: Without knowing Asterisk specifics, you could make it type "exit<ENTER>" using something like `bind -s ^d exit\r`

Comment: You could also try `bind ^d ed-end-of-file`

Comment: It looks like the Asterisk bindings are [here](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/6b2d9451741cadb080637190af65d40f692d67ed/main/asterisk.c#L3051). It makes Ctrl+D redisplay the screen, basically doing nothing.

Comment: when I add `bind ^d ed-end-of-file` to `/etc/editrc`, then ctrl+d functions same as enter, ie new line. Before I added it, it had no function (nothing happened when I pressed ctrl+d)

Comment: currently, `ctrl+c` basically acts as exit/quit. Is there a way to disable `ctrl+c`, and make `ctrl+d` do what `ctrl+c` used to do ?

Comment: That's unfortunate. Asterisk also doesn't seem to provide libedit with a way to bind to exit natively. Please try the other suggestion to make it type exit then enter

Comment: Interesting. What does `bind` show that Ctrl+C is currently bound to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108713/discussion-between-400-the-cat-and-mikel).

Comment: I think it's bound to `ed-tty-sigint`. So you could do `bind ^d ed-tty-sigint`

Comment: that gives me `bind: Invalid command 'ed-tty-sigint'`